# Determine variables with matrix

Tags: matrix-equations

The task is to find the variables a, b so that, the planes $E1, E2 $ and $E3$,

1) have no common point

2) have a common point

The equations are:

$$E1: 1x - 1y - 1z = -2$$

$$E2: 3x +1y -1z = b$$

$$E3: ax + 8y+2z =7$$

I think task 1 has to solved like this: Means one line gives no sense:

$$        \begin{pmatrix}
        x & y &  z & ? \\
        x & y &  z & ? \\
        0 & 0 &  0 & 4\\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

2 like this so that there is a unique solution:

$$        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 &  0 & ? \\
        0 & 1 &  0 & ? \\
        0 & 0 &  1 & ?\\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

Are my two approaches correct? And how should i start? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing in matrix form and row--reducing,
$$\eqalign{\pmatrix{1&-1&-1&|&-2\cr 3&1&-1&|&b\cr a&8&2&|&7\cr}
  &\sim\pmatrix{1&-1&-1&|&-2\cr 0&4&2&|&b+6\cr 0&8+a&2+a&|&7+2a}\cr
  &\sim\pmatrix{1&-1&-1&|&-2\cr 0&4&2&|&b+6\cr 0&0&2a-8&|&-20+2a-8b-ab\cr}\ .\cr}$$
The planes have no common point if these equations have no solution, which occurs when
$$2a-8=0\ ,\quad -20+2a-8b-ab\ne0\ .$$
They have a unique common point if
$$2a-8\ne0\ ,$$
and more than one common point (in fact, infinitely many) if
$$2a-8=0\ ,\quad -20+2a-8b-ab=0\ .$$
You can now solve these equations to find the actual values of $a$ and $b$ in the various cases.

**Comment**.  Unless your instructor insists on it, there is no need to reduce the left hand side to just $1$s and $0$s.

Comment: Thanks! Its really a very good answer! I only had some problems to undestand your last transformation: Maybe you can explain it further? I opened a new question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/834695/transformation-of-matrix-with-variables

Comment: The answer to your other question is fine, though you can do it in one step as $4$ times row 3 minus $a+8$ times row 2.  In fact, to be strictly accurate, I simplified the algebra by first doing row 3 minus $2$ times row 2, then $4$ times row 3 minus $a$ times row 2.