# Transformation of matrix with variables

Tags: matrices

I have this matrix:

$$\eqalign{\pmatrix{1&-1&-1&|&-2\cr 3&1&-1&|&b\cr a&8&2&|&7\cr}
  &\sim\pmatrix{1&-1&-1&|&-2\cr 0&4&2&|&b+6\cr 0&8+a&2+a&|&7+2a}\cr
  &\sim\pmatrix{1&-1&-1&|&-2\cr 0&4&2&|&b+6\cr 0&0&2a-8&|&-20+2a-8b-ab\cr}\ .\cr}$$

My question is, how did the editor come from:

$$        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 4 & 2 & | & b +6 \\
        0 & 8 +a & 2 + a  &|&  7 +2a\\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

to:

$$        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 4 & 2 & | & b +6 \\
        0 & 0 & 2a - 8  &|&  -20+2a-8b-ab\\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First subtract from the third line (in the original matrix) $2 + \dfrac{a}{4}$ times the second line. Then multiply the third line by $4$.